# Matlab and RLC analysis

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to plot the response of a series RLC circuit to a step function using Matlab.

I've read a bit around it, but I can't get it to work.  Help would be much appreciated.

Here is my Matlab code:

```
solution = dsolve('square(5, 50) / ((47*10^(-3) * 1*10^(-6))) = D2y + 220/(47*10^(-3)) * Dy + 1/(47*10^(-3) * 1*10^(-6)) * y', 'y(0) = 0', 'Dy(0) = 0', 'x');
ezplot('solution');
```

The values of the RLC circuit are:
\$R = 220\Omega\$, \$L = 47\$mH and \$C = 1\mu\$F.
The equation for the capacitor voltage (which is what I'm tring to plot) is:
$$v''(t) + \frac{R}{L}v'(t) + \frac{1}{LC}v(t) = \frac{v_s}{LC}$$

\$v(t)\$ is the capacitor voltage and \$v_s\$ is the source voltage (which is a \$5\$Vpp square wave).

Comment: What do you mean "can't get it to work"? No output? Wrong output? Errors?

Comment: The output is the line y = x (which is completely wrong).

Comment: First thing: shouldn't be the third term v(t) instead of v'(t)?

Comment: Yeah, I made a mistake in the question (though in my code it's correct).

Comment: And sorry but what's square()?

Comment: A function to create a square wave. "SQUARE(T,DUTY) generates a square wave with specified duty
    cycle. The duty cycle, DUTY, is the percent of the period
    in which the signal is positive."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Description of equations]

[image: Figure swhoing overshoot]

You see there's a slight overshoot, if you are familiar with "damping coefficient" (or you can look it up) you'll see that tinkering with the values of L & C will vary the overshoot (or eliminate it).

You can download the PDF instead of the images if you wish to have it on your computer:

http://bit.ly/StepResponseRLC

Any further questions, feel free.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Do you know of a way to generate the response to a sine wave?  So step is for step function.  What would be for sine?  Do I have to use lsim?

Answer (score 1):

I am not too sure of doing it the way using differential equations.  I am more familar iwth laplace transforms.

```
C=1/sC
L=sL
R=R
```

When you have the laplace equation to describe the transfer function in the form of num/den arange by the s terms

```
num = [a b c]
den = [d e f]
```

where a,b,c and are the double zero, zero and unit
and d, e, and f are the double pole, pole and unit

then using the transfer function and step commands

```
sys=tf(num,den);
step(sys);
```

for a simple R,C,C circuit the following example:

```
R1 = 20e3;
C1 = 235e-9;
R2 = 2e3;
C2 = 22e-9;
num = [2*R2*C1 0];
den = [C1*R1*C2*R2*2 (2*C1*R1 + C2*2*R2) 2];
sys = tf(num,den);
step(sys);
```

alternatively with the differential equations you could put them directly into state space form and use the step command.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Unfortuantely, I have not yet done poles and zeros; however, I've done the Laplace transform.  I was just wondering how you know what a b c d e f are supposed to be.  Perhaps you could tell me the topic this falls under and I can just read about it.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `square()` isn't an analytical function, and AFAIK Matlab doesn't have such a thing. `square(t,duty)` is a "conventional" Matlab function that takes a vector `t` and outputs a vector of the same length. The 5 that you use in `square(5, 50)` is actually interpreted as a single item time vector and simply resolves to the integer -1 when evaluated.

```
>> square(5, 50)
ans =
    -1
```

You might be able to trick Matlab in to working with the `square()` function by performing some symbolic toolbox trickery, but I'd rather suggest you rewrite your problem and use a numeric solver like `ode45()` to plot the response for a given time period.

Additionally, to plot an analytical function named `solution` you should run `ezplot(solution)` (without the quotes)

Answer (score 0):

you can use rlcdemo (gui)

Analyzing the Response of an RLC Circuit
   This demo shows how to use the Control System Toolbox(TM) functions
   to analyze the time and frequency responses of common RLC circuits
   as a function of their physical parameters.